# Like boxn ot working.

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, dreamweaver, facebook-likebox

I see this question asked 1000 times but nothing seems to be working. I have this webpage http://www.authenticmainelobster.com/ and I`m trying to get a face book like button. I`ve tired and watched a few how too's. I`m using Dream weaver cs6. The code I am getting from face book is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.authenticmainelobster.com/" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
```

^^ for html and I have also used  IFRAME

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.authenticmainelobster.com%2F&amp;width=The+pixel+width+of+the+plugin&amp;height=80&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:The pixel width of the pluginpx; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Nothing shows up or the link just shows up depending on what I type. I`ve also used the DM widget and it shows up on the preview but when I place it on the page I want nothing happens its just a box.

Any idea's

Thanks,
Ga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think where you are going wrong is you're putting the URL http://www.authenticmainelobster.com/, where you should be putting your Facebook Page URL, which should be something like "http://www.facebook.com/AuthenticMaineLobster" (or whatever your actual FB page is.)